# Can PPP CHAP authentication use Cisco "Type 5" MD5 passwords?

Tags: cisco, authentication, point-to-point-protocol

Looking over Cisco's [documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk713/tk507/technologies_tech_note09186a00800b4131.shtml), and [RFC 1994](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1994.txt) (PPP CHAP authentication), my initial guess is "no", because CHAP requires a cleartext password to rehash every time it sends a challenge.

Is this true? If so, is there another way to configure CHAP so it doesn't use the easily-decoded type 7 passwords?

The Cisco device in question uses local authentication, not a TACACS+ or RADIUS server. Would using RADIUS eliminate the problem or just move it to the RADIUS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, CHAP needs a cleartext password.

Moving authentication to a Radius server would not eliminate the need of cleartext passwords,  but at least all passwords would be stored into a central and secured repository.